# CodeIgniter gives 403 access forbidden error while updating a form

Tags: codeigniter, centos7

I am having a

> 403 access forbidden

issue when updating any form. Otherwise all the website is  working fine.

I have codeigniter as framework & centos 7 is the Operating system. I have checked all the permissions but I'm unable to find the solution.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the right file permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting crazy with this. After to do a lot of things i found the solution.
Just disable ModSecurity on your Cpanel.

If you don’t have access to this option, contact your host provider and say that you want to disable this option temporarily or forever.

Comment: it would be nice if you could update your question, stating that you are on a shared hosting, to make the whole Q/A more valuable for others who might find themselves with the same problem